# Print to file produces unwanted text

Tags: java, arrays, text, pretty-print

I have something like this:

```
private void myPrinter(int[] arr) throws IOException{
    FileWriter outFile = new FileWriter("myFile.txt",true);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outFile);
    //BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(outFile);
    //PrintStream out=new PrintStream(outFile);
    for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        System.out.print(arr[i]+" ");
        out.print(arr[i]+" ");   
    }
    System.out.println();
    // out.newLine();
    out.println();
    //out.flush();
    out.close();
}
```

When it prints an array with 100 elements it is fine. **When it comes to print an array with more than 255 elements it produces something like ‱‰‱‱‱‱‰‰‱‱‰‱਍** When I add 
    `out.print(" "+arr[i]+" ");` i.e space in front of `arr[i]` it is fine. However, I do not need that extra space at the front and I don't understand why it is needed.
This method is called in a for loop iterating around a 2D array.  console prints it fine but in txt file is printed as shown above.  The code that is method is called is as follows:

```
 final int[] anArr=init();
 for (int idz=0;idz< z;idz++ ){
     int[] toBe=new int[anArr.length];
     System.arraycopy( anArr, 0, toBe, 0, anArr.length );
     arr[z]=create(toBe);
     try {
         myPrinter(arr[z]);
     } catch (IOException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

I tried adding a line before anything is printed and it works. However, when I later manually remove the line from the txt file and save, it turns back to the gibberish text. Is there something wrong with my txt configurations or something else?

Comment: fyi, you can just do `print(arr[i] + " ");`

Comment: Show the code where `myPrinter` method is called.

Comment: Adding [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that actually reproduces this behaviour would be helpful.

Comment: `arr[z]=create(toBe);` what this method is doing?

Comment: It randomly changes some of the values of the array. But since this works fine for console output, why not for txt file output?

Comment: `if ((i % 50) == 0) { out.flush(); }` might help too, but it should not be necessary. By the way `z < z` in the `for` seems a bit off.

Comment: Start using IO Commons .

Comment: how do you open your text file? I seems odd that the problems reappear after you remove the empty line in front of your file. consider using gVIM as an editor (for this situation, as a test.)